# make an element fixed if scrolled more than 140px from top

Tags: jquery

As it says in the Q, I want to make an element fixed if I scroll the page down more than 14px.

I tried the following but for some reason it is not working.

```
$(window).unbind('scroll').scroll(function () {
    if ($('body').scrollTop > 140) {
        $('div.top-logo-main').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
        $('div.top-logo-main').css('position', 'static');
    }
});
```

Comment: I would use `$(this).scrollTop() > 140`

Answer (score 3):

Use scrollTop() as its functtion

```
$(window).unbind('scroll').scroll(function () {
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 140) {
        $('div.top-logo-main').css('position', 'static');
    } else {
        $('div.top-logo-main').css('position', 'fixed');
    }
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/djgNG/

Its all right I got what you mean, check this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/djgNG/2/

Comment: I actually changed the order of `static` and `fixed`. In any case, it does turn to `fixed`, but it does NOT revert back to `static` if I go back up and scroll top is less than 140. Why?

Comment: Its all right I got what you mean, check this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/djgNG/2/

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` is a function. Call it (note the parenthesis):

```
if ($('body').scrollTop() > 140) {
```